# Facebook share shows 404 page not found

Tags: php, facebook-sharer

While sharing the following link `https://cargo2share.com/ru/blog/aerophobia` in facebook I am getting 404 page not found preview. When I share it in Google+, Vk.com or in another networks it shows the correct page and image in preview. Any ideas?

Comment: If you share with a mobile app try with a desktop version because I see a similar problem on mobile.

Comment: I tried on my PC, the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Rinos comment I could find the right solution. Apparently, Facebook has cached this page before it was existing. I had to go to Facebook Sharing Debugger under https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing and for my URL press the `Scrape Again` button to renew the cached information.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=https://cargo2share.com/ru/blog/aerophobia&title=[YOUR TITLE HERE]">facebook share</a>
```

Comment: This solution is just letting me replace the "404 not found" text with "my title". But it is not fixing the problem. The image and meta description are still from "not found page"